# Android fragments over each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been working with fragments for a while now, but I regularly encounter a problem that just annoys me. Fragments remain drawn over each other some times. Now, I managed to isolate one use case for this, and it goes like this:

[Add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) `Fragment A` (also use [addToBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) with a name `"backstack_state"`)

[Replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) `Fragment A` with `Fragment B` (use `addToBackStack`)

Replace `Fragment B` with `Fragment C` **WITHOUT** using `addToBackStack`

at a given point use `popBackStack("backstack_state", 0)` and here comes the issue:

The backstack is popped until `Fragment A` but `Fragment C` is overlaid with `Fragment A`, both are visible at the same time. Is this normal behavior or is it me who makes a mistake?

Here's a remark also: all the fragments have transparent background.

Thanks!

Comment: The `Fragment` back stack is confusing to work with to say the least. Additionally `Fragments` on the back stack among other things still consume memory and that makes adding `Fragments` to the backstack not very good from a performance point of view. My advice is: Just don't add `Fragments` to the back stack (in most cases it is bad design anyway). Use `Activities` instead to build the navigation tree.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the top fragment (in this case Fragment C) is not removed. You have to remove it first inside a fragment transaction. Try this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (topFragment != null) {
    fragmentTransaction.remove(topFragment);
}    
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentManager.popBackStack("backstack_state", 0);
```